# Why does a single child of a horizontal linear layout need a weight to be centered horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

In the following the yellow and teracotta bars are both horizontal linear layouts each containing an image view with `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`.

Why is the top image view not therefore horizontally centered despite its layout_gravity setting being horizontal?

In order to get the image view to be centered horizontally I had to add a `layout_weight` of 1 (the terracotta bar). But I do not understand why this is so, why isn't specifying a `layout_gravity` of `center_horizontal` sufficient to center the image?

Also why is this only an issue with horizontal linear layouts, with a vertical linear layout it is not necessary to add the layout_weight in order to center the image, as is done in the green bar.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Horizontal_LL_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f3ff36">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHLL1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/pizzahut" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Horizontal_LL_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff4c44">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHLL2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/pizzahut" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Horizontal_LL_3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff39e3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHLL3a"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/pizzahut" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewHLL3b"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/pizzahut" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Vertical_LL_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#9eff9a">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewVLL1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/pizzahut" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you missed layout_weight=1 for the first parameter

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you mean it is not present in the imageViewHLL1 then that is what my question is specifically about. Quote: "In order to get the image view to be centered horizontally I had to add a layout_weight of 1. But I do not understand why this is so"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not needed. You can simply set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` on the `LinearLayout`.

If you don't, the views are stacked on the left by default. If you specify a weight of 1, the space allocated to the View will be the full width of the LinearLayout instead, and then layout_gravity allows you to align the View inside this allocated space.